# why java7 gives error output for sums of double

Tags: java, double, java-7

I tried the following program

```
class test{
public static void main (String argv[]){
    double x = 0.1;
    double y = 0;
    for (int i =0;i<10 ; i++){
        y=y+x;
        System.out.println (y);
    }
}
}
```

but it gives the following output

```
0.1
0.2
0.30000000000000004
0.4
0.5
0.6
0.7
0.7999999999999999
0.8999999999999999
0.9999999999999999
```

Why does java7 give this instead of just 0.3 or 0.8  ...!

I tried the following in online java compiler as well
http://ideone.com/g0bYad

Answer (score 1):

Floating point numbers (including Java's `double` type) aren't completely precise. See [how they encode information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) for more details. You can see that not all numbers have an exact IEEE 754 64 bit representation

Answer (score 0):

Floating point values lack an exact precision. That's their nature. Try using the BigDecimal class.